# SQL query ; horizontal to vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, unpivot

I'm stuck with a SQL query (SQL Server) that involves converting horizontal rows to vertical rows

Below is my data

```
No      Flag_1    Flag_2    Flag_3
---      ----      -----     -----
A         1         2         3
B         4         1         6
```

After conversion , the table should be

```
No     FlagsName    Flag_value
--      ----        ----------
A        Flag_1        1
A        Flag_2        2  
A        Flag_3        3
B        Flag_1        4
B        Flag_2        1
B        Flag_3        6
```

Any input on this would be helpful?

I'm trying to play around `ROW_NUMBER` over partition. but it is not working somehow !!!

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL`:

```
select No, 'Flag_1' as FlagName, Flag_1 as Flag_Value
from yourtable
union all
select No, 'Flag_2' as FlagName, Flag_2 as Flag_Value
from yourtable
union all
select No, 'Flag_3' as FlagName, Flag_3 as Flag_Value
from yourtable
```

Or an `UNPIVOT`:

```
select no, FlagsName, flag_value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
    flag_value
    for FlagsName in (Flag_1, Flag_2, Flag_3)
) u
```

## See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7922d/3)

Comment: I like using UNPIVOT as it reads better and also concise. So, how do they compare with each other performance-wise?