# Switch rows to columns to generate report - MySql

Tags: mysql, report

I have a simple database (using MySql) with which I need to generate a report.

I have a table that contains weekly logs which are submitted by users. Each of these logs have states, such as: submitted, approved, etc.

```
LogSubmissions Table
+----+--------+--------+---------+-------+
| id | weekId | userId | info... | state |
+----+--------+--------+---------+-------+
|  0 |      0 |     1  | data... |     0 |
|  1 |      0 |     2  | data... |     1 |
|  1 |      0 |     3  | data... |     1 |
|  2 |      1 |     1  | data... |     0 |
```

I also have a table which keeps track of the weeks.

```
WeekManager Table
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
| id | startDate | EndDate | ...     |
+----+-----------+---------+---------+
|  0 | Date1     | Date2   | ...     |
|  1 | Date3     | Date4   | ...     |
|  2 | Date5     | Date6   | ...     |
```

I need a report which displays the weeks as columns as well as the names from a user table. It should display the state of the weekly log the user submitted. For example Bob submission for Week 1 has a state of 0.

```
Report
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Name | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | ...   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| Bob  |      0 |      1 |      0 | ...   |
| Joe  |      1 |      1 |      1 | ...   |
| Jim  |      0 |      0 |      0 | ...   |
```

I am having a bit of trouble getting this report working. My major obstacle is that weeks are added, so the amount of columns for report will vary.

This [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns) helped quite a bit, however it only deals with a static amount of rows. I need something that varies depending on the amount of weeks. I was thinking of using a loop of some kind to achieve this, however I'm not sure if that is possible.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

User Table:

```
User Table
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | ...     |
+----+------+---------+
|  0 | ...  | ...     |
|  1 | ...  | ...     |
|  2 | ...  | ...     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table structure is not exactly clear (for example I don't see where you get `user name`).

The basic set up for a *pivot* in MySQL uses an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression similar to this:

```
select 
  l.userid,
  max(case when w.id =0 then l.state end) Week1,
  max(case when w.id =1 then l.state end) Week2,
  max(case when w.id =2 then l.state end) Week3
from LogSubmissions l
left join WeekManager w
  on w.id = l.weekid
group by l.userid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55991/3).

Edit, if you have an unknown number of weeks then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic sql:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when w.id = ',
      id,
      ' then l.state end) AS Week',
      id + 1
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  WeekManager;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT l.userid, ', @sql, ' 
                  from LogSubmissions l
                  left join WeekManager w
                    on w.id = l.weekid
                  group by l.userid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55991/6)

Comment: Thanks for you help. However weeks will be added, I need a query that will create columns based on the number of weeks.

Comment: @computer10171 see my edit, I included a dynamic version for unknown data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to convert a horizontal table into a vertical one (temp table if you will).  Use union all do this as per this previous post: [SQL query ; horizontal to vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501766/sql-query-horizontal-to-vertical) .